# QLibray segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, fault, qlibrary

I try to use external library. When i call function from this library it is work correct.
But then i try call this function in the loop i have Segmentation fault. Code for example:

```
char *snam = (char*) new char;

QLibrary swedll("swedll32.dll");

typedef  char * (*Fct)(int, char *);
Fct fct=(Fct)(swedll.resolve("_swe_get_planet_name@8"));

for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
{
    if (fct) fct(0,snam);
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef char * (*Fct)(int, char *); Fct fct=(Fct)(swedll.resolve("_swe_get_planet_name@8"));
```

must change to

```
typedef __stdcall char * (*Fct)(int, char *); Fct fct=(Fct)(swedll.resolve("_swe_get_planet_name@8"));
```